# Git svn rebase: file out of date - trailing whitespace

Tags: git, svn, whitespace, trailing, dcommit

I have an issue while using git svn. I have a repor which is used by people mostly from Windows but I use Linux.

I have performed changes on this repo but today I got this after `git svn dcommit`:

```
Could not chdir to home directory /isource/home/pmalek: No such file or directory
        M       robot_tests/XXXXX-XXXXX_tests/testcases/03.01.test.tsv
        M       robot_tests/XXXXX-XXXXX_tests/testcases/XXXXXKeywords.tsv
        M       robot_tests/common_keywords/XXXXXKeywords.tsv

ERROR from SVN:
Transaction is out of date: File '/trunk/robot_tests/XXXXX-XXXXX_tests/testcases/XXXXXKeywords.tsv' is out of date
W: 1638177d0f033905043ff0fd9507e9fc30f39db6 and refs/remotes/git-svn differ, using rebase:
:040000 040000 c6f5f770f94b1b46310a4c20f09f2da3e2d1d806 9f378428c1211f60bcabd96f2c3b0e9794dbd90a M      robot_tests
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: Test | XXXXX TA tests refactored
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M       robot_tests/XXXXX-XXXXX_tests/testcases/XXXXXKeywords.tsv
<stdin>:12: trailing whitespace.
${test_Filename} XXXXX_test.xml
<stdin>:14: trailing whitespace.
${configFilename}       xxxxtest.xml
<stdin>:18: trailing whitespace.
Topology file in XXXXX bin directory    [Documentation] file in XXXXX bin directory
<stdin>:19: trailing whitespace.
        [Timeout]       30 seconds
<stdin>:23: trailing whitespace.
        SSHLibrary.File Should Exist    ${XXXXXdirectory}/bin/${test_Filename}
warning: squelched 93 whitespace errors
warning: 98 lines add whitespace errors.
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
/home/XXXXX/libexec/git-core/git-am: line 179: git-merge-recursive: command not found
Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0001 Test | XXXXX TA tests refactored
The copy of the patch that failed is found in: 
   /home/xxxxx/_svn/trunk/.git/rebase-apply/patch

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".

rebase refs/remotes/git-svn: command returned error: 1
```

I have a clean commit in my local repo but cannot do the `git svn dcommit`. 
File to commit has trailing whitespaces but it's ok.

What should I do ?

I have tried many things in `.gitconfig` but none worked. Current `.gitconfig`

```
[core]
   autocrlf = true
   whitespace = cr-at-eol
```

Comment: What is the command you executed to get the output?

Comment: @LarsNoschinski `git svn dcommit` - added to question

Comment: The whitespace shouldn't be the relevant problem here. I am confused about the missing `git-merge-recursive`. Does `git merge-recursive` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git svn dcommit` only works if your git branch is a superset (i.e., more current than) the newest SVN revision). If this is not the case, you have to import the new SVN commits first. This is done via `git svn rebase`.

Comment: I get nearly the same output when I launch `git svn rebase` (the top part with `ERROR from SVN` is missing).

Comment: Ok, this means this is neither a problem with whitespace, nor is it directly svn-related. `git svn rebase` pulls in the current SVN revisions and tries to rebase your commit on top of these. During this, conflicts occur, which it tries to resolve via merge-recursive (which seems to be missing), but this fails. So you need to resolve the conflicts manually. Using `git mergetool` might help. You probably find further hints if you look for rebase and conflicts.

Comment: `git merge-recursive
usage: git merge-recursive <base>... -- <head> <remote> ...` - it's there ... :(

Comment: The problem was with the merge operation itself (my friend committed over my changes before I'd put it in the repo)